# Misconception about left censoring

Tags: survival, censoring

While trying to learn about censoring, I stumbled across a sentence on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Censoring_(statistics)) which I do not understand:

> A common misconception with time interval data is to class as left
> censored intervals where the start time is unknown. In these cases we
> have a lower bound on the time interval, thus the data is right
> censored (despite the fact that the missing start point is to the left
> of the known interval when viewed as a timeline!).

I know what right and left censoring means but I have trouble following this reasoning. Maybe somebody here could help me and explain what they mean!

Answer (score 10):

This is a statement about subtraction and absolute value of real numbers.

In the context we must understand a "time interval" as being an interval of the form $[A,B]$ where one or both of the endpoints is a random time.  The object of study is the duration $X=B-A.$

When the start of the interval $A$ is not known, but only the fact that $A\le a$ is known (with $a$ marking the beginning of the study period), the variable $A$ is *left censored*.  However, the value of the duration $X$ when the end of the interval $B=b$ is observed is

$$X = b-A \ge b-a,$$

which is *right censoring*.

Answer (score 5):

This can be very confusing.

Start with a simple situation, when `time = 0` is both the time of study entry and the time of starting some therapy, for example in a cancer outcome study in which you want to evaluate time to death after therapy starts. If Participant A both enters the study and starts therapy at `time = 0`, and is still alive at `time = 2 years`, then you know that the time between starting therapy and death will be *at least* 2 years for Participant A. That's standard right-censoring at 2 years.

Now say that Participant B enters your study after having started treatment at some prior unknown time. You don't know exactly when treatment began, so you call `time = 0` for Participant B the time of study entry. If Participant B dies at `time = 2 years`, you know that the time between starting therapy and death was *at least* 2 years. That's logically the same as for Participant A: in both cases, you have a *lower limit* on the time between starting therapy and death. That's right censoring on the survival time of interest in both cases.

Potential confusion with Participant B can come from losing the more typical association of lack of an event with right censoring, which you do have with Participant A. With Participant B you observe an event but you don't know the actual elapsed time from starting therapy to death, so you have to treat that event time (starting from your `time = 0` at study entry) as a right-censored observation.